# login in Lithium doesnt work on host

Tags: php, frameworks, lithium

I'm using default settings in Lithium, default adapter is php, everything is quite default. On my localhost I can login, add users, but when I copied everything to my host (fixed all db errors) I can't login. The code is fine.

Now I can make users and everything works except login. It seems that it can't find username/password in db that match inputs becouse it shows me an error msg - Login failed. How that's possible?

Like I said, everything is default and works on my localhost, if you need to see other code, just ask.
**controller:** http://pastium.org/view/8a23279872e04753b84c93923ad2e61e

Comment: Can you paste your login authentication code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is identical, chances are that you have environment-depending configurations in place (like db connections) or more likely Auth class setup!

Remember that if you're not on localhost, lithium assumes (by default) that you are in production mode!

Answer (score 0):

What version are you running? Had the same problem before when I ran 0.10 (the .dmg from SourceForge). However, if you clone the latest version from [GitHub](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium), your should be fine.

Also, remember that if you use a "`form Auth`" – your password will be hashed automatically, remember to store your passwords hashed too.

Comment: I had a similar problem to the OP. Turns out that when you hash the password, the string length is 60 characters while I had my password field set at 40. I corrected it locally but forgot to update the remote database.